# How to change from command line the Bundle identifier of an App extension?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcodebuild, ios-app-extension

I have an app extension that I want to use in several projects that all have different bundle identifiers. The problem is that App extension bundle identifiers must have a prefix consisting of their containing application's bundle identifier followed by a '.'. Is there a way to change via a command line tool the bundle identifier of the app extension? something similar to what we can do with codesign to change the signature of an app? I'm under Delphi so I do not use xcode to develop my app (but the app extension is made with xcode)